# Como fazer um onclick com update no banco de dados?

Tags: javascript, sql-update, onclick

Estou com dúvida de como fazer um onclick clicando ja faça um update no banco de dados

Comment: Antes de qualquer coisa, comece fazendo o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como a comunidade funciona; depois leia o guia de [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) para verificar como pode melhorar sua pergunta e, por fim, acesse a [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para verificar vários artigos que te lhe ajudarão a entender melhor o site.

Answer (score 2):

Partindo do ponto que não foi especificado a linguagem utilizada (PHP, .Net, Node.JS), nem o banco, fica difícil lhe ajudar.

Mas basicamente, para sistemas web, o onClick dispara um HTTP, seja GET, POST, PUT ou DELETE, via ajax, que recebido no backend, deve fazer a operação no banco de dados.

Procura tópicos como, Ajax, e CRUD PHP ou CRUD + Linguagem utilizada.

Abraços.